# Making fixed header and scrollable content

Tags: html, css

Plz I want to ask how to make the following:

- Fixed background for all (header & content) >>> I made it well.
- Fixed header while the content scrolls >>> I made it well.

But the issue is: since I'm using a fixed background image, and the fixed header is transparent; when the page scrolls, the content appear under the header (because it's transparent) ..... I've tried to gave the header the same background of the body and it gone well on the desktop, but it appears abnormal on the iPad! that's why I've resorted to make the header transparent and then the problem appears.

```css
body {
  background-color: #080717;
  background-image: url('../images/fixedBG.jpg');
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.myHeader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 255px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.container {
  margin: 255px auto 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 541px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="myHeader">
  <header>
    <a href="index.php"><img alt="" src="images/bigLogo.png"></a>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a> </li>
      <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a> </li>
      <li><a href="ceo.php">CEO</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>bla bla bla long text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you make a fiddle

Comment: Go on this website http://jsfiddle.net and put your code into the right boxes so people can test

Comment: Also please can you post some HTML

Comment: by saying abnormal on ipad you mean it's bigger than you thought ?

Comment: @Ahmad: The background scrolls and appears not fixed (because it's repeated for the header and body)

Comment: @HishamRamadan I think background is fixed. The container has fixed width that makes scroll. While the header is still fixed in lower screens also.

Answer (score 0):

**iPad Fix**

Mobile Safari (like Chrome for Android, Mobile Firefox and IE Mobile) increases the font size of wide blocks (at all times), such that if you double-tap to zoom in on that block (which fits the block to the screen width), the text will be legible. If you set -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% (or none), it won't be able to do this, and so when a user double-taps to zoom in on wide blocks the text will be illegibly small; users will be able to read it if they pinch-zoom in, but then the text will be wider than the screen and they'll have to pan horizontally to read each line of text!

Ideally you would fix this by using Responsive Web Design techniques to make your design adapt to mobile screen sizes (in which case you would no longer have any very wide blocks, so mobile browsers would no longer adjust your font sizes).

Finally if you really need to prevent Mobile Safari from adjusting your font sizes you can set -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%, but do this only as a last resort since it is likely to cause mobile users to have difficulty reading your text, as it'll either be too small or they'll have to pan from side to side after every line they read. Note that you must use 100% not none because none has nasty side-effects in desktop browsers. There are also equivalent -moz-text-size-adjust and -ms-text-size-adjust properties for Mobile Firefox and IE Mobile.

Edit: for example in your case the simplest is probably the 2nd alternative, so you could try adding the following CSS:

```
/* Mobile browsers only */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   .newsletter_input {
        width: 320px;
    }
    .newsletter_input #form{
        font-size:42pt
    }
}
```

Though it's not ideal to hardcode 320px like this; you could improve on that by using a variety of CSS media queries, or getting the device-width from JavaScript.**strong text**

**Scrollbar fix**

CSS Part

overflow property has to be set

```
.myHeader {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 255px;
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

hope this fixes your issue